# VB.net windows application retrieve values based on multiple unique row values

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working on VB.net Windows application. I have a database table with unique Employee Ids. If the user enters multiple employee Id in text box.I want to display the result of the query with text box input( Ex 001, 002,003) concatenated with where IN query to display the result into gridview.

Example:

Select * from Employees where Employeeid IN(textbox values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the values from your text box if the value in the text box are comma separated and the field is numeric in the table.

```
sql = "Select * from Employees where Employeeid IN("+ textbox.text +")"
```

If the user dint add comma separated then you can use **Replace** function

```
sql = "Select * from Employees where Employeeid IN( "+ textbox.text.Replace(" ",",") +")"
```

If your EmployeeId column is not numeric then you have to use single quotes with every value entered in the text box. i.e `In('121','123','124')`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any way if we can validate when the user misses comma in  between two ids.

Comment: if the user misses comma then you can add replace function. That will replace the SPACE with COMMA,

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do what you are doing.  It is incredibly vulnerable to SQL Injection.  If you do not know what this is, then please Google it.  What would happen if someone entered in your TextBox "1,2); DELETE FROM Employees WHERE 1 IN (1,2"?

If you must allow multiple selection it is much better to do so via e.g. a ListBox showing all possible values, with SelectionMode MultiExtended.  You are then in control of arranging the choices into a safe SQL command to send to the database.

Edit

As a secondary point, if your employee ids are in the form 001, 002, 003 etc then they are some form of string/varchar/text, in which case all the elements in the IN () will need to be surrounded by single quotes.  Again far easier not to rely on your users knowing this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but my table has 30000 rows and it is highly impractical with this much of data to select multiple search item for the query from listbox items. Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In which case have a TextBox and a Button and make your ListBox dynamic. Enter a value in TextBox, and click button to add it to ListBox checking first that the value in TextBox is required length and contains no restricted words or characters (e.g. ";").   Then build your SQL from the contents of the ListBox.  But I am slightly mystified, if there are 30,000 rows, how anyone is expected to know the EmployeeId for the Employee they want.  Don't you need to ability to filter by Name, Department etc.?